# Unique combinations from multiple columns in python or anything

Tags: python, r, excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Unique combinations from multiple columns, no sequence. I am trying to list all unique combinations of multiple elements (example). 3 elements from a column without sequence A B C will duplicate B A C and neither A A A should be shown. appears as well. A, B, C, A B, A C, B C, A B C should be displayed. Use column names to find all unique combinations. and counts the values that are 1 based on all unique combinations. such as the following information

## this is my code in python but count is worng

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

# Create a DataFrame with the data
data = {
    'A': [1, 1, 0],
    'B': [0, 1, 0],
    'C': [0, 1, 1]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Generate unique combinations of columns
unique_combinations = set()
for r in range(1, len(df.columns) + 1):
    unique_combinations.update(combinations(df.columns, r))

# Create a DataFrame to store combinations and counts
count_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Combination', 'Count'])

# Count the occurrences of 1 in each combination
for combo in unique_combinations:
    combination_data = df[list(combo)]
    count = combination_data.all(axis=1).sum()
    count_df = count_df.append({'Combination': ', '.join(combo), 'Count': count}, ignore_index=True)

# Sort the DataFrame by count
count_df.sort_values(by='Count', ascending=False, inplace=True)

# Print the resulting DataFrame
print(count_df)
```

**thanks for helping**

```
Count Unique combinations from multiple columns, no sequence. 
`data = {
    'A': [1, 1, 0, 1],
    'B': [0, 1, 0, 1],
    'C': [0, 1, 1, 0]
}

will get value
 Combination  Count
0         A      1
1         B      0
2         C      1
3      A, B      1
4      B, C      0
5      A, C      0
6   A, B, C      1
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might just have the wrong representation for what you are counting.  If you have the unique combination `A`, and you want to find rows in `data` that match exactly `A=1`, that implies all other columns are `=0`.

Here, we can make a binary-encoded series of your combinations:

```py
ncols = df.shape[1]

for combo in sorted(unique_combinations):
    # binary encoding for the combination, true only if the symbol is in combo
    combo_series = pd.Series(np.zeros((ncols,), dtype=int), index=df.columns)
    print(combo_series.to_dict(), combo)
    # find the rows where we get an exact match in all columns, and sum
    count = df.eq(combo_series, axis='columns').all(axis='columns').sum()
```

then the rest of your code will produce the counts that you want.

Testing with some data that has a higher count by repeating the last entry a couple of times:

```
data = {
    'A': [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    'B': [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    'C': [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
}
```

yields a count of 3 for (A,B):

```
  Combination Count
0           A     1
1        A, B     3
2     A, B, C     1
3        A, C     0
4           B     0
5        B, C     0
6           C     1
```